# Wordpress query exclude post format form last posts widget

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently developing a Wordpress theme for a project and im looking for a way to exclude posts format from my widget and just keep the standard post format to show in the widget and i dont know where i have to put the code to exclude the post formats 
and this the code of my tabs widget

```
<?php
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'widget_tabs_box' );
function widget_tabs_box(){
register_widget( 'widget_tabs' );
}
class widget_tabs extends WP_Widget {
function widget_tabs() {
$widget_ops = array( 'description' => 'Most Popular, Recent, Comments, Tags'  );
$this->WP_Widget( 'widget_tabs',theme_name .'- Tabbed  ', $widget_ops );
}
function widget( $args, $instance ) {
<if( empty($instance['posts_number']) || $instance['posts_number'] == ' ' || !is_numeric($instance['posts_number']))    $posts_number = 5;
    else $posts_number = $instance['posts_number'];
?>
<div class="widget" id="tabbed-widget">
    <div class="widget-container">
        <div class="widget-top">
            <ul class="tabs posts-taps">
                <li class="tabs"><a href="#tab1"><?php _e( 'Popular' , 'aya' ) ?></a></li>
                <li class="tabs"><a href="#tab2"><?php _e( 'Recent' , 'aya' ) ?></a></li>
                <li class="tabs"><a href="#tab3"><?php _e( 'Comments' , 'aya' ) ?></a></li>
                <li class="tabs" style="margin-left:0"><a href="#tab4"><?php _e( 'Tags' , 'aya' ) ?></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="main-warp">
        <div id="tab1" class="tabs-wrap">
            <ul>
                             <!--latest news--> 
                <?php aya_popular_posts( $posts_number ) ?> 
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tabs-wrap">
            <ul>
                <?php aya_last_posts( $posts_number )?> 
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tabs-wrap">
            <ul>
                <?php  last_comments( $posts_number );?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="tab4" class="tabs-wrap tagcloud">
            <?php wp_tag_cloud( $args = array('largest' => 8,'number' => 25,'orderby'=> 'count', 'order' => 'DESC' )); ?>
        </div>
     </div> 
    </div>
</div><!-- .widget /-->
<?php
}
function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
$instance = $old_instance;
$instance['posts_number'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['posts_number'] );
return $instance;
}
function form( $instance ) {
$defaults = array( 'posts_number' => 5 );
$instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults ); ?>
<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'posts_number' ); ?>">Number of items to show : </label>
<input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'posts_number' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'posts_number' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['posts_number']; ?>" size="3" type="text" />
</p>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

and this is the code of the last posts function

```
function aya_last_posts($numberOfPosts = 5 , $thumb = true){
global $post;
$orig_post = $post;
$lastPosts = get_posts('numberposts='.$numberOfPosts);
foreach($lastPosts as $post): setup_postdata($post);
?>
<?php if ( function_exists("has_post_thumbnail") && has_post_thumbnail() && $thumb ) : ?>   
   <div class="hole-post">      
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'aya' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php aya_thumb('aya-medium'); ?><span class="overlay-icon"></span></a>
    </div><!-- post-thumbnail /-->
<?php endif; ?>
<span class="ss-view">
        <?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID());?>
      </span>
<div class="tabtitle"><h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo the_title(); ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a></h3></div>
</li></div><?php endforeach;  $post = $orig_post;  }
```

Comment: guys pleaase help me with this problem i need to know the answer

Comment: Why is it relevant to show the tabs widget? is that what you call standard post format? If not, what would be standard post format?

Comment: my tabs widgets is with big thumbnail so when i post i new post like quote or link without set up a featured image for the post that create a problem in the style of the site and i mean with standard post format the normal one   and i did show the widget cuz i dont know where i have to post the code pf exclude pleaase help

Comment: see my answer. If it doesn't work we can tamper a bit more with the function.

Answer (score 0):

If the last posts section is giving you troubles because of the image thumbnail, the fastest way would be to remove the image from the block. it seems the function accepts a second parameter so, instead of

```
<?php aya_last_posts( $posts_number )?>
```

try with

```
<?php aya_last_posts( $posts_number,false )?>
```

and see if it works.

As a sidenote: I see a closing `</li>` element inside the function. I'm pretty sure that there was an opening tag accidentally removed.

Edit: I saw your clarification. Look at the bennining of `aya_last_posts`, it says

```
$lastPosts = get_posts('numberposts='.$numberOfPosts);
```

[get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) accepts parameters such as how many posts to retrieve, and of which type.

Just replace it with

```
$lastPosts = get_posts(array('numberposts'=>$numberOfPosts,'post_type' =>'post' ));
```

See the link to find out what else you can customize on get_posts. Perhaps you could pull only posts with a given tag or from a given category.

Comment: thank's for ur effort but i wanna keep the thubs but i want that the widget show only the standard post format like no link no quote no gallery no aside no chat and i did found this code but i dont know wher i should put it                                                     `$args = array(
 'numberposts' => 10,
 post_type' =>'post',
 'tax_query' => array(
 array(
 'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
 'field' => 'slug',
 'terms' => array( 'post-format-quote','post-format-link' ),
 'operator' => 'NOT IN',
 ),
 )
 );
 $posts= get_posts($args); `

Comment: `function aya_last_posts($numberOfPosts = 5 , $thumb = true){
 global $post;
 $orig_post = $post;
 $args = array(
 'numberposts' => $numberOfPosts,
 'post_type' =>'post',
 'tax_query' => array(
 array(
 'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
 'field' => 'slug',
 'terms' => array( 'post-format-quote','post-format-link' ),
 'operator' => 'NOT IN',
 )));`

Comment: it still not working heil pleaase i did the code that i did right in the comment and i think the post formats get excluded but the function dosent show the recent post any more like just random what to do

Comment: what i want is just standard recent posts only

Comment: The code you quoted in your comment is doing a pretty obscure filter I don't get. Please try using was I wrote in my answer. Just numberpost and post_type operators. If it fails, feel free to pm me or email me. It's my nick at gmail dot com

Comment: yes i post ur code but it fail  
what i want is just standard recent posts only and is this is ur email nick@gmail.com ?